# How kube-apiserver communicates with kubelet with cacerts?

Tags: kubernetes, certificate, tls1.2, ca, kops

I have a kubernetes cluster created with kops. And I see the below in apiserver commandline arguments.

```
--kubelet-client-certificate=/srv/kubernetes/kubelet-api.pem 
--kubelet-client-key=/srv/kubernetes/kubelet-api-key.pem
```

How does a single cert and key will be used to communicate to all the worker nodes? Since I can see each worker node has its own certificate and root ca.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find below the extract from kubernetes documentation. It says that certificates are not validated when api server makes connection to kubelet.

The connections from the apiserver to a node, pod, or service **default to plain HTTP connections and are therefore neither authenticated nor encrypted.** They can be run over a secure HTTPS connection by prefixing https: to the node, pod, or service name in the API URL, **but they will not validate the certificate provided by the HTTPS endpoint nor provide client credentials** so while the connection will be encrypted, it will not provide any guarantees of integrity. These connections are not currently safe to run over untrusted and/or public networks.